# Prove that $\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1} (f_{k}(x))^{n}\right)^{1/n}\leq n^{1/n}f_{n}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to prove that \begin{align}\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1} (f_{k}(x))^{n}\right)^{1/n}\leq n^{1/n}f_{n}(x),\end{align}
given that $0\leq f_{k}(x)\leq f_{k+1}(x) ,$ for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$ and $x\in[a,b].$

**PROOF**

Let $x\in[a,b],$ then
\begin{align}\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1} (f_{k}(x))^{n}\right)^{1/n}&\leq\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1} (f_{n}(x))^{n}\right)^{1/n},\;\;\text{since}\;\;f_k(x)\leq f_n(x),\;k\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}\\&\leq\left((f_{n}(x))^{n}\sum^{n}_{k=1} (1)\right)^{1/n}\\&= n^{1/n}f_{n}(x),\end{align}
Thanks to xbh for the hint!

Comment: Do we have $f_1 \leqslant f_2 \leqslant \dots \leqslant f_n$ additionally?

Comment: @ xbh: Oh, yes!

Comment: Then this is pretty evident.

Comment: What you have done  does make sense.  That is indeed the proof.